# How to close borderlines in table?

Tags: tables

I have a table like this:

[image: tab]

And how could I close the missing borderlines lines in the table?

code:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{test1} & \textbf{test2} &\textbf{test3} \\ \hline
    abc &  abc  & abc  \\ 
    & abc \\ \hline
    abc  & abc &  abc  \\ 
    & abc \\ \hline
    abc & abc & abc    \\ 
    & abc \\ \hline
    abc & abc & abc    \\ 
    & abc \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{test}
\label{t:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: use 3 cells in each row so `& abc & \\  `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thank you for your help I am closing the topic.